# Exemplo input tirar valor e fazer console log com esse valor quando clica no botão enviar com React

Tags: html, react

Ao clicar no botão enviar quero tirar o valor de input e fazer console log do valor inserido pelo o utilizador! Penso que seja simples mas o que estou tentando fazer é mais complexo mas servirá para implementar no que preciso!

Feito com **React**

- Input
- Botão enviar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua tag `<input />` deverá ter o atributo refs e crie também um botão para disparar uma função. Exemplo

```
<input type='text' ref='nome' />
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick }>Enviar</button>
```

Crie a funçao `handleClick()`

```
handleClick(){
 const value = this.refs.nome.value;
 console.log(value);
}
```